# Generating code coverage using jasmine-sbt plugin

Tags: unit-testing, playframework-2.0, sbt, jasmine, code-coverage

I am using sbt-jasmine-plugin for unit testing my java script files. However, i am not sure how to generate the coverage report using this plugin. Anybody using the same plugin, generating the code coverage for the js files??

Comment: I don't think you can achieve it with the Jasmine plugin, as Jasmine does not do code coverage. You may need another tool, like e.g. Istambul (https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul)

Comment: i have used karma before in different projects. But current project does not use nodejs for karma to work. So i was thinking of using some kind of plugin which can be used in my plugin.sbt file without installing separately through npm. so any such plugin that can be used with jasmine for code coverage.